# ¿Por qué un clasificador de red neural para problemas de clases múltiples clasifica sólo en una clase cuando un árbol de decisión es más preciso?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redes-neuronales

Quiero crear un clasificador para un marco de datos que tiene cuatro clases. Tengo dos modelos predictivos: una red neuronal y un clasificador de árbol. Pero ponen a todos en una clase, durante el entrenamiento y por lo tanto durante las pruebas.

## Red neuronal clasifica en una clase

El problema es que la clasificación de mi red neuronal es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llamo a la modelo aquí:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = create_model(x_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[1])
epochs =  30
batch_sz = 64

print("Beginning model training with batch size {} and {} epochs".format(batch_sz, epochs))

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("lc_model.h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, mode='auto', period=1)


# train the model
history = model.fit(x_train.to_numpy(),
                y_train.to_numpy(),
                validation_split=0.2,
                epochs=epochs,  
                batch_size=batch_sz, 
                verbose=2,
#                 class_weight = weights, # class_weight tells the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented grade class.
#                 callbacks=[checkpoint]
                   )

# revert to the best model encountered during training
model = load_model("lc_model.h5", compile=False)
```

Aquí está la arquitectura del modelo:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import MaxNorm
# from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt

def create_model(input_dim, output_dim):
    print(output_dim)
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    print("sequential")
    # input layer
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=input_dim, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(3)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    # hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(3)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    # output layer
    model.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax'))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss=focal_loss(alpha=1), loss_weights=None, optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Aquí hay una parte de `x_train`.

```
id reg  0.0_x   1.0_x   17.0    21.0    30.0    40.0    50.0    60.0    70.0    Célibataire     Divorcé(e)  Marié et j'ai des enfants à charge  Marié et je n'ai pas encore d'enfants à charge  Refus de répondre   Veuf (ve)   1er cycle universitaire / Licence   2e cycle universtaire / Master  3e cycle universtaire / Doctorat    BTS     Je n'ai jamais été à l'école    Niveau collège  Niveau lycée    Niveau primaire     Autre. Merci de préciser :@NS$  Infirme     J'ai une société    Je ne travaille pas     Je suis commerçant  Je suis encore étudiant     Je suis independent     Je suis journalier, je travaille de temps à autre   Je suis retraité    Je travaille dans le secteur privé  Je travaille dans le secteur public     0.0_y   250.0   3750.0  7500.0  8750.0  11250.0     11500.0     18750.0     25000.0     35000.0     45000.0     50000.0     0.0_x.1     1.0_y   0.0_y.1     1.0_x.1     Je ne suis pas d'accord     Je suis d'accord    False_x     True_y  False_y     True_x  False_x.1   True_y.1    False_y.1   True_x.1    False_x.2   True_y.2    False_y.2   True_x.2    False_x.3   True_y.3    False_y.3   True_x.3    False_x.4   True_y.4    False_y.4   True_x.4    False_x.5   True_y.5    False_y.5   True_x.5    0.0_x.2     1.0_y.1     0.0_y.2     1.0_x.2     0.0_x.3     1.0_y.2     0.0_y.3     1.0
0   NaN     0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1
1   NaN     0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
...
```

Y aquí está parte de `y_train`:

```
   Voting intention in 2021_Cast a blank vote   Voting intention in 2021_I know who I will be voting for in 2021    Voting intention in 2021_I won't vote   Voting intention in 2021_I'm going to vote in 2021 but don't know for who
0                0                                  1                                                                       0                                                                       0   
1                0                                  0                                                                       0                                                                       1
...
```

Así que cuando intento probar este modelo no es mejor que el azar:

```
sequential
Beginning model training with batch size 64 and 30 epochs
WARNING:tensorflow:`period` argument is deprecated. Please use `save_freq` to specify the frequency in number of samples seen.
Train on 768 samples, validate on 192 samples
Epoch 1/30
768/768 - 1s - loss: -inf - acc: 0.2448 - val_loss: -inf - val_acc: 0.2708
Epoch 2/30
768/768 - 0s - loss: -inf - acc: 0.2409 - val_loss: -inf - val_acc: 0.2708
...
Epoch 30/30
768/768 - 0s - loss: -inf - acc: 0.2409 - val_loss: -inf - val_acc: 0.2708
```

De hecho, la precisión está justo por debajo del 25%, que es un resultado que habría esperado de la selección aleatoria de las clases. Y parece que nunca se aprende nada ya que la pérdida es siempre "-inf".

Así que calculo la precisión del modelo en el equipo de pruebas y es aún peor. De hecho, con el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

y_pred = model.predict(x_test.to_numpy())

# Revert one-hot encoding to classes
y_pred_classes = pd.DataFrame((y_pred.argmax(1)[:,None] == np.arange(y_pred.shape[1])),
                              columns=y_test.columns,
                              index=y_test.index)

y_test_vals = y_test.idxmax(1)
y_pred_vals = y_pred_classes.idxmax(1)

# F1 score
# Use idxmax() to convert back from one-hot encoding
f1 = f1_score(y_test_vals, y_pred_vals, average='weighted')
print("Test Set Accuracy: {:.2%}   (But results would have been better if trained on the FULL dataset)".format(f1))
```

Obtengo: `"Test Set Accuracy: 10.92%"`

No lo entiendo, es una arquitectura que había logrado poner a trabajar en [otro problema de clasificación de préstamos](https://medium.com/universal-mind/predicting-loan-grades-with-a-neural-network-a-machine-learning-pipeline-on-aws-65d5e1d2f08e).

### With weights:

Todas las modelizaciones anteriores no estaban ponderadas o no tenían pérdida focal.

Traté de hacer frente al desequilibrio de clase de manera diferente, como el remuestreo. Sin remuestreo lo hice con pesos:

```
weights = df_en2['Voting intention in 2021'].value_counts(normalize=True)
weights = weights.sort_index().tolist()
weights = {0: 1 / weights[0],
           1: 1 / weights[1], 
           2: 1 / weights[2],
           3: 1 / weights[3]}
```

Donde `dfen_2` es el dataframe que da `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_test`, `y_test` con la función `spilt_data()` que puedes encontrar [aquí](https://github.com/antoinecomp/multiclass_prediction/blob/master/Loans.ipynb) (Es básicamente la misma arquitectura pero para el problema de clasificación de préstamos).

## Clasificador de árboles multiclase

En comparación, con un clasificador de árboles, si dejo `max_depth` a "ninguna", las hojas se expanden hasta que todas las hojas son puras o hasta que todas las hojas contienen menos de muestras divididas. Y obtengo una precisión promedio del 42%.

```
# importing necessary libraries 
from sklearn import datasets 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

# dividing X, y into train and test data 
# X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0) 

# training a DescisionTreeClassifier 
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
dtree_model = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(x_train, y_train) 
dtree_predictions = dtree_model.predict(x_test) 

# creating a confusion matrix 
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test.values.argmax(axis = 1), dtree_predictions.argmax(axis = 1))
```

Y devuelve:

```
array([[0.19047619, 0.15873016, 0.45454545, 0.27118644],
       [0.15873016, 0.38095238, 0.2       , 0.30508475],
       [0.15873016, 0.15873016, 0.4       , 0.22033898],
       [0.19047619, 0.19047619, 0.21818182, 0.38983051]])
```

Comment: Podrias partir con un set de datos más acotado donde el set de train y test sea el mismo para comprobar la capacidad de aprendizaje de tu modelo. Esto tiene que ser con 1 o 2 ejemplos a ver si logra aprender algo, luego extrapolas a un set de datos con más ejemplos, para descartar problemas en los datos, y finalmente el caso final deberá ser el que tienes en tu pregunta; donde el set de entrenamiento y test sean disjuntos, para así finalmente medir su capacidad de generalización.

Comment: @Vichoko Sí, añadí la precisión durante el entrenamiento y se puede ver que val_loss es `-inf`. Así que el modelo no aprende nada. He añadido los resultados de un árbol de decisiones que es mucho mejor que el anterior.

Comment: podrías probar con el modelo de regresión logistica múltiple